# how can I use goto statment in plsql block?

Tags: plsql, goto

How Can I Write a PL/SQL block to display the multiples of a Given Number without including multiples of 10 for a given range (Start Value and End Value), using `GOTO`.

Comment: Can you first include them all, then get a list of the multiples of 10, and then do a *set difference*?

Comment: The better question would be "How can I NOT to use `goto` statement". Try to avoid it by all means possible.  Unconditional branching can be a real hassle.

Answer (score 1):

The `GOTO` statement consists of two parts - the `GOTO` statement and the `Label Declaration`:

```
GOTO label_name;
```

And then, use below just above the code to move the control to specific line of code.

`<<label_name>>`